# CIImage and CIFilter implementation specifics

Tags: ios, performance, core-graphics, core-image, cifilter

I have a question about the underlying implementation of the **Core Image** system. I'm adding some `CIImages` on top of each other. Not that much, about 5 or 6 of them. To save memory and performance, they all have their transparent pixels cropped. They are then drawn at **offsets**, so I'm using a `@"CIAffineTransform"` filter to position them.

```
CIFilter* moveFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAffineTransform"];
```

**My question is:** does the moveFilter.outputImage REALLY generate a new image, or does it generate "render settings" that are later on used to draw the actual image?

*(If it is the first, that would mean I'm effectively rendering the image twice. It would be a huge flaw in the Core Image API and hard to believe Apple created it this way.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters do not generate anything. `outputImage` does not generate anything. CIImage does not generate anything. All you are doing is constructing a chain of filters.

Rendering to a bitmap doesn't happen until you explicitly ask for it to happen. You do this in one of two ways:

- Call CIContext `createCGImage:fromRect:`.
- Actually draw a CIImage-based UIImage into a graphics context.

Comment: But then when I start rendering, does it create intermediate bitmaps under the hood, or does it set the transformation matrix for the draw operation? Looking at the performance, it seems to do the first.

Comment: When you do either of the two things I bulleted, then and only then all the rendering happens, kaboom. This can be time-consuming on iOS, which doesn't have the math cojones for some filters (such as Gaussian blur; indeed, some filters are off the table completely for this reason). Nothing else connected with CIFilter / CIImage takes any time / space at all. Basically you are just making me repeat myself...

Comment: Yes, in my comment, I asked, when the rendering starts (one of your two bullet points), does it do: combine 2 images into new texture => use new texture in next filter - or - does it do: combine 2 images (or affine transform and an image) into "rendering pipeline settings" to be drawn on the final target texture?

Comment: In game engines the 2nd option is used. But looking at the performance With and Without a simple TRANSLATION MATRIX, it seems like iOS is CREATING AN ADDITIONAL texture under the hood to output to the final image.

Comment: CIFilters can be darned slow on an iOS device, that's for sure - as I already mentioned in a previously comment. They were devised for the desktop, where the processor is orders of magnitude more powerful. This is why there are alternatives like [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) - you might give it a try.